# xfce4-terminal doesn't want to directly run middle click paste (after upgrade from Mint 20.3 to Mint 21)

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, xfce4-terminal

I just upgraded from Mint 20.3 XFCE to Mint 21 XFCE. All is well, but the xfce-terminal doesn't directly execute anymore the pasted commands (which contain Enter at the end). Previously, when I copied a command, or a sequence of commands from a text file or a website, and then pasted them (with middle mouse click) directly in the xfce-terminal, it simply ran them. Now, it marks the pasted text white and wants me to hit ENTER. What happened, how can I make it simply run the pasted text directly just like it used to?

Comment: Turn off bracketed paste. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202732/prevent-multi-line-paste-in-bash

Comment: @Quasímodo that was it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As the user "Quasímodo" above pointed out it his comment, the solution is to turn off bracketed paste:

So add this to `~/.inputrc`:

```
set enable-bracketed-paste Off
```

restart Bash

Strange, I don't remember doing that before. Is that new for Ubuntu 22?